# Delete items that are empty or null - JS - MYSQL - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a big list of products, and then i display that on another page, but i need display just the items that had some value, if in DB the item is null, or 0, i need delete it from the list.

The code for the list ais as follow:

```
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>

    * {

    box-sizing: content-box;

    }

    li {

    display: block; }

    body {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: lightgray;

    }

.header h1 {

    color: black;
    background-color: #87c587;
    font-weight: italic;
    text-align: center;
    /*border: 1px solid white;*/
    /*border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;*/
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
#nome1 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="header"> 

    <h1>lista de <span id="nome1"></span></h1>

</div>

<ul id="populate"></ul>

<li>Açúcar: <span id="acucar"></span></li>

    <li>Aveia: <span id="aveia"></span></li>

    <li>Catchup: <span id="catchup"></div></li>

    <li>Caldo de Carne: <div id="caldodecarne"></div>

    <li>Caldo de galinha: <span id="caldodegalinha"><span></li>

    <li>Caldo de legumes: <span id="caldodelegumes"><span></li>

    <li>Extrato de tomate: <span id="extratodetomate"></span></li>

    <li>Gelatina em pó: <span id="gelatina"></span></li>

    <li>Iogurte de frutas: <span id="iogurtedefrutas"></span></li>

    <li>Leite de coco: <span id="leitedecoco"></span></li>

    <li>Macarrão instantâneo: <span id="miojo"></span></li>

    <li>Massa de lasanha: <span id="massadelasanha"></span></li>

    <li>Óleo: <span id="Oleo"></span></li>

    <li>Sal: <span id="Sal"></span></li>

    <li>Suco de frutas: <span id="sucodefrutas"></span></li>

    <li>Adoçante: <span id="Adocante"></span></li>

    <li>Azeite: <span id="Azeite"></span></li>

    <li>Bebida láctea: <span id="gelatina"></span></li>

    <li>Cereal: <span id="Cereal"></span></li>

    <li>Creme de leite: <span id="CremeDeLeite"></span></li>

    <li>Fermento biológico: <span id="Fermento"></span></li>

    <li>Geleia: <span id="geleia"></span></li>

<input style="text-align:center;" id="nome" name="nome" type="text">

    <input type="submit" id="lstButton" name="lstButton" value="Confirmar nome">

</ul>
```

the script for check the tag name and then exclude ```display: none;" is as follow, but not working.

```
document.getElementById("lstButton").onclick = delNoSelectedProducts;

function delNoSelectedProducts()

 { 

var produtos = document.getElementsByTagName("LI").value;

if(produtos == '' || produtos == null) 

{ 

produtos.style.display = "none";

} 

} 
</script>
```

and my Ajax/jQuery is very basic...:

```
    $(document).ready(function()

    {
    var url = "lista.php";

    $('#lstButton').on('click',function(e)

    {

        var nome = $.trim($("#nome").val());
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax(

        {

            type: "POST",
            action: $(this),
            crossDomain: true, 
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {nome:nome},        

            success:function(data)

            {
                if(data.status == "success")

                {
                    //$('#populate').html(result); // doesn't work. 

                    $('#acucar').html(data.result.acucar);
                    $('#aveia').text(data.result.aveia);
                    $("#caldodecarne").text(data.result.caldodecarne);
                    $("#caldodegalinha").text(data.result.caldodegalinha);
                    $("#caldodelegumes").text(data.result.caldodelegumes);
                    $("#catchup").text(data.result.catchup);
                    $("#extratodetomate").text(data.result.extratodetomate);
                    $("#gelatina").text(data.result.gelatina);
                    $("#iogurtedefrutas").text(data.result.iogurtedefrutas);
                    $("#leitedecoco").text(data.result.leitedecoco);
                    $("#leite").text(data.result.leite)
                    $("#miojo").text(data.result.miojo);
                    $("#massadelasanha").text(data.result.massadelasanha);
                    $("#oleo").text(data.result.Oleo);
                    $('#Suco').text(data.result.Sal);
                    $('#Adocante').text(data.result.adocante);
                    $('#Azeite').text(data.result.Azeite);
                    $('#Cereal').text(data.result.Cereal);
                    $('#CremeDeLeite').text(data.result.cremedeleite);


                    //$('.user-info').slideDown();

                }
                    else

                {
                    //$('.user-info').slideUp();
                    $('#status").text("error");
                } 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

in the server is all ok, but i don't get it how to populate all list with one unique id, then i'm doing in that way...

I'll apreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A variable can't be both '' and null, which is what you're checking for. Us the OR operator instead of &&:

```
if(produtos == '' || produtos == null)
```

Comment: Right! Now i get this error ```TypeError: produtos is undefined```. How is not defined, if i declared above?

Comment: You had a typo in Elements where you declare the variable. Did you just fix that (I can't see it now)

Comment: oh... i just write wrong the ```document.getElementsByTagName```. Was missing the the ```s``` in ```Elements```